# Responsive design fluid images idea

Tags: javascript, css, responsive-design

I am trying to create a page where appropriate images to load are determined by javascript, based on browser size. For example:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" />
```

javascript would change it to:

```
<img src="image1_800px.jpg" />
```

and load the 800px wide image version.

Doing this is not a problem. Problem arises when i try to do the same for browsers without javascript. The basic idea would be to hide images initially and display them with a style in NOSCRIPT tag. So browsers that support javascript will change image urls and make those images visible and browsers that don't support javascript will simply unhide those images by css. The problem is that images with display:none are loaded by browsers. And adding image url into anything but the src attribute is not an option as such image would rely on javascript to set its src.

So are there any ideas if it's possible to make this work?

For instance: i could rewrite image src attributes on domready and hope that browsers don't manage to start loading images from old src, but would that be the case? If so - would it always be the case or would some browsers work differently?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for is http://adaptive-images.com/ - it uses Javascript to determine image size, but also has a back-up option if the user does not have Javascript enabled that still provides the resized image (with caveats, read the docs).

Comment: Not exactly what i'm looking for. My server-side implementation is different and there's no proxy php script like in adaptive-images. For security and performance reasons my solution is URL rewrite based and it does not execute PHP if the resized image already exists. So cookies won't work here since images are fetched directly bypassing PHP in absolute majority of cases. Adaptive-images is an alternative i already knew about, but i'd only use it if i couldn't find how to make my own idea work.